# Highcharts custom xAxis label

Tags: javascript, highcharts

what I need is grouped xAxis label.

I created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9nhk544b

In that fiddle, I use category like: foo1, foo2, foo3, bar1, bar2... so on. What I need is 2 line xAxis label like:

```
y|
 |
 |
 |___________________________________________
   1    2    3     1    2    3    1    2    3
       foo             bar             baz
```

I've googled for days and still get nothing, is that even possible ? is there any trick to get it done ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of some example data you want to plot like this ? It will help us get an answer for you.

Comment: Its not really clear what you want, but have you tried Categories?
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories

Comment: You can have multiple xAxis like this, but depends on how you wish to use them.
http://jsfiddle.net/W43Zb/138/

Comment: @SteveP fiddle added

Comment: @SaadFarooq, ha, that close thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Black Label's Grouped categories plugin for this: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories

Answer (score 1):

You can use [grouped categories](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories) plugin which allows to add two axis.